# In Android devices when entered lengthy text and unfocus the control, text is not displaying from starting

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In Android devices when entered lengthy text and unfocus the control text is displayed from middle and not from starting point, is there any solution to make start text visible on un focusing the entry control.

Tried [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuzmn.png) and Gravity properties of Control. Image added for reference

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution to make start text visible on un focusing the entry control?

No. I referred to the [doc about Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry) and tested code. For Entry, it can't make start text visible when unfocused.

However, you can use Editor to avoid it. Thanks to its support for multi-line input. And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/cjTF31r).